# give item direction and speed from the way i swipe on the screen

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on a game in cocos2d. The game has multiple sprites coming on the screen. I would like to change that items direction ato the direction a swipe and the speed to how fast i swipe . Does anyone know how i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com) (improved Cocos2D) will have [built-in gesture recognition](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/Kobold2D/html/interface_k_k_input.html) starting with Preview 5.

Answer (score 1):

[UISwipeGestureRecognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) sort of do what you are asking, although you are limited on the directions you can use. If you want to implement any direction, simply make some code that figured out the direction and speed in the `touchesMoved:` method. [This](http://www.71squared.com/2009/12/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-11-joypad/) is a great tutorial on how to get the direction, and also has code which you can modify to get the speed. Simply get the distance and see how long it took to get there, and that gives you the speed. Hope that Helps!

Comment: so cocos2d doesn't have a special way to deal with touch for sprites?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without the gesture recognizer, here's a simple D.I.Y solution: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/7925